# ML models takes a lot of time and does not seem to end

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am using ML (org.apache.spark.ml.regression) algorithms for machine learning.
Below is my code and it runs forever and does not end even after an hour:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, OneHotEncoder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.GBTRegressor
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.GBTRegressionModel
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df_train = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(data_path_train).select(all_toUse_name.head, all_toUse_name.tail: _*).withColumn(target_col_name, col(target_col_name) cast DoubleType)

val index_transformers: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] = char_col_toUse_names.map(
  cname => new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol(cname)
    .setOutputCol("int_"+cname)
)

val one_hot_encoders: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] = char_col_toUse_names.map(
  cname => new OneHotEncoder()
    .setInputCol("int_"+cname)
    .setOutputCol("one_hot_"+cname)
)

var one_hot_col_names = char_col_toUse_names.clone
for((x,i) <- char_col_toUse_names.view.zipWithIndex) one_hot_col_names(i) = "one_hot_"+x

val col_name = one_hot_col_names++num_col_toUse_names
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(col_name).setOutputCol("features")

val gbt_model = new GBTRegressor().setLabelCol(target_col_name).setFeaturesCol("features").setMaxIter(2).setMaxDepth(2)

var stages: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] = index_transformers ++ one_hot_encoders :+ assembler :+ gbt_model

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(stages)

val trained_model = pipeline.fit(df_train)
```

I had the same problem when I used MLLIB (where the training model was not the part of the pipeline) but this was solved using sc.parallelize (as shown in the last line). Same data now takes less then 5 mins to finish using org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.GradientBoostedTrees.

**Note:** The code below might be wrong at many places but it finishes when we add sc.parallelize and it also hangs forever when we dun use sc.parallelize.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, OneHotEncoder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.GradientBoostedTrees
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.BoostingStrategy


val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df_train = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(data_path_train).select(all_toUse_name.head, all_toUse_name.tail: _*)

val index_transformers: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] = char_col_toUse_names.map(
  cname => new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol(cname)
    .setOutputCol("int_"+cname)
)

val one_hot_encoders: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] = char_col_toUse_names.map(
  cname => new OneHotEncoder()
    .setInputCol("int_"+cname)
    .setOutputCol("one_hot_"+cname)
)

var one_hot_col_names = char_col_toUse_names.clone
for((x,i) <- char_col_toUse_names.view.zipWithIndex) one_hot_col_names(i) = "one_hot_"+x

val col_name = one_hot_col_names++num_col_toUse_names
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(col_name).setOutputCol("features")

var stages: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] = index_transformers ++ one_hot_encoders :+ assembler    
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(stages)        
val indexed_df_train = pipeline.fit(df_train).transform(df_train);

val trainingData = indexed_df_train.select(col(target_col_name).cast("double").alias("label"), col("features")).map(row => LabeledPoint(row.getDouble(0), row(1).asInstanceOf[Vector]))    

var boostingStrategy = BoostingStrategy.defaultParams("Regression")
boostingStrategy.numIterations = 10 // Note: Use more iterations in practice.
boostingStrategy.treeStrategy.maxDepth = 10
boostingStrategy.treeStrategy.categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()

val model = GradientBoostedTrees.train(sc.parallelize(trainingData.collect()), boostingStrategy)
```

How do we solve this, also in the last method one might argue that `sc.parallelize(trainingData.collect())` 
converts an RDD to dataframe and then back to RDD, but then this speeds up the computation here.

My Guess (which might be all wrong) is that ML algorithms deals with DataFrame and not RDDs, sc.parallelize gives out RDDs and so ML algorithms can never be used with sc.parallelize. If that's the case, how to make sure the code finishes quickly when using ML algorithms (instead of MLLIB).

regards

Comment: Your guess is wrong for sure. Why do you see different behavior? For starters model you try to train with ML and MLlib are not equivalent. The latter one assumes `one_hot_col_names` to be continuous features, the former one to be categorical. Moreover one hot encoding doesn't make particular sense here.

Comment: Thanks @zero323 for the help. So do you think the first code is correct (ignoring the need of one hot encoding) and it should run fine (end on time) ?

If yes, then why this code with a 10 MB file take more than hour and still does not end :(

Comment: A wild guess is that GBT isn't converging with ml with default hyper-parameters while as in MLlib, you've specified the max depth, number of iterations and so on...

Comment: for now:

val gbt_model = new GBTRegressor().setLabelCol(target_col_name).setFeaturesCol("features").setMaxIter(2).setMaxDepth(2)

Comment: And that doesn't finish ?

Comment: No sir :(

Last log:
16/06/01 01:26:09 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 29.0 (TID 55). 2227 bytes result sent to driver
16/06/01 01:26:09 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 29.0 (TID 55) in 29 ms on localhost (1/2)

Comment: How many observations and variables do you have ?

Comment: (column Index, distinct values in each column) ==>

(0,9), (1,523), (2,604), (3,38), (4,6), (5,117), (6,300), (7,12), (8,3), (9,3), (10,4), (11,2)

Comment: My advice is to start with removing all the junk code (one hot and stuff) and testing equivalent models by passing `categoricalFeaturesInfo` to MLlib.